# Parse through string and delete tags and text

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, string, replace

The web request works fine and everything has gone as planned, but for some reason i cannot seem to grab and remove that one piece of the string. the removal below is one attempt of many,

*I don't have the source on my person, so I'll try to recreate it.*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Net; 
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

public partial class test : System.Web.UI.Page
{

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        byte[] srs = new byte[8192];
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http:"+//mywebsite.com/getsearchresults/page.aspx="+ result["x"]);

        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        Stream xStream = response.GetResponseStream();

        string myString = null;
        int count = 0;

        do
        {
            count = xStream.Read(srs, 0, srs.Length);
            if (count != 0)
            {
                myString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(srs, 0, count);
        //regex ismatch = new myString.regex (@"\The Following Results Are\b")
        //ismatch = regex.replace("The Follwing Results Are","",1);         
                   sb.Append(myString);
              }
            }
            while (count > 0);
            printresults.Text = sb.ToString();

       }

   }

}
```

Comment: Err... your code is a bit of a syntactic mess. While still somehow understandable, it's clear that this would not work. But due to the amount of typos, it's hard to tell what's actually wrong. So I guess it would help if you presented some compilable code.

Comment: Also an explanation would go a long way.

Comment: the only part of the code im concerned with working is the part that removes "the following results" as i stated i dont have access to the code so i wrote it from memory. everything in it works fine accept the string manipulation. i dunno if that helps any. The website timeout when i wrote the question so my explaination seems to have gone missing. (I need to grab a few words from the html being passed in and remove them. the words do not have a class so i cant grab them by their tags or class name)

Answer (score 0):

Well your RegEx is wrong. I don't see how you expect the pattern `@"\The Followin Results Are\b"` to match "The Follwing Results Are"

There are a couple of problems, firstly, the pattern begins with a `\` which is not in the input, I believe that is just being interpreted as a literal. `\t` would match a tab and that's not in the input either so it's wrong either way. The second problem is `\b` which matches a backspace or word boundary. I don't think that will work here either because the input ends at the end of that word and a word boundary finds a match when you have `\w\W` (a word character followed by a non word character). There is no boundary there because there it's the end of the input.

Unless you're greatly concerned about multiple occurrences of "The Following Results Are" you should simply be calling the `string.Replace` method like so;

```
 string foo = oldString.Replace("The Following Results Are", System.String.Empty);
```

If you need to be sure only the first occurrence is replaced you should do;

```
 RegEx rgx = new RegEx("The Following Results Are");
 string foo = rgx.Replace(oldString, System.String.Empty, 1);
```

Comment: im not just want to read thru the requested html and get rid of "the following results" and then spit it onto the page

Comment: okay thank you for your help, ill see what i can do and update accordingly

Comment: @user1902540 Either of those suggestions should fix it. Your RegEx was simply wrong. It would not match "The Following Results Are" it would match "*from this tab* The Following Results Are *to the start of this word, including the space*"